# Memory Allocation And Caching Of Delegates

Tags: c#

I was recently surprised by the way the compiler caches delegates when use use non-capturing delegates and lambdas. Take the following code (available at [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACgL8BmAAiNoGFaKBvC2z+4pelWgKoBnGAAoAlgDsALrQRpaU2QE8AlBy7tyXHbQD0e2gEEANiYhgAhtJhDaGGCZgBzazFoAHGFFpWzG3VoAZQgAWxgAWRhpAAsIDFEjDAxVAG5AjJ0A3WydAyZLMBjbe0cXNwUMCFtJAHJZSzMLN1yuEPCo2PjRUXlaNVoAXgA+Y2TehTU0lm0M1s5803MrGzsHJ1cbT29fRpN54LDI6LiEgBlmkySU1IOD/MZC4rWyzZhK6qE6hqaVmAP2scuglRJYFMBVENRhc/NdQeDVGk7rNAvgeIoZLQYY04UpaGCMbIIQctJkdPgAOz42jYWjAW4o3QAX2yLMZ2TRvDxuMxfTxamypIylLkNP6DJ0bKyjM5hMOHRO3XwAFYADxKBQawmjABmAFdJGB1IyhaiqfrDaJiApCEjGWymUA=)):

```
using System;

public class C 
{
    static void Use(int x, int y)
    {
        // #1 - Allocates delegate per call
        SomeMethod(Add);                 
        
        // #2 - Caches delegate, doesn't allocate each time
        SomeMethod((x, y) => Add(x, y)); 
        
        // #3 - Allocates delegate per call
        SomeMethod(LocalAdd);
        
        // #4 - Caches delegate, doesn't allocate each time
        SomeMethod((a, b) => LocalAdd(a, b));
        
        static int LocalAdd(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
    
    static int Add(int x, int y)
    {
        return x + y;
    }
    
    static int SomeMethod(Func<int, int, int> func)
    {
        return func(1, 2);
    }
}
```

I was surprised to see that in case #1 and #3 the compiler doesn't bother to cache the `Func` delegate it creates. I did wonder if the reason for #1 is down to historic reason (maybe this is how it was done before generics and lambdas), but the fact that passing the local function directly does the same suggests otherwise.

So, my question is, why doesn't the compiler cache the delegate it all cases? It seems odd that I have to use the more wordy lambda syntax in order to create a cached value. Why do I have to rewrite this:

`SomeMethod(LocalAdd);`

as

`SomeMethod((a, b) => LocalAdd(a, b));`

In order to get the compiler to cache the delegate and therefore generate less garbage?

Answer (score 2):

This topic has been discussed for quite some considerable time, and can be summarized as: changing it *could* present detectable changes that could lead to changes in behavior, and lead to bugs in code that currently works. The scenarios in which this applies are pretty niche, and relate to reference equality tests against the delegate instance.

The impacted code would be pretty negligible, but: non-zero, and usually the default is "retain compatibility", if an optimization can change behavior.

Comment: That might be true in case #1, but there's no need to retain compatibility in the case where you are passing a static local method (case #3).

Comment: @Sean there's nothing at all different about case #3 - except perhaps you could say "different rules for local methods", but when you have unexpected different rules, that's when things get *even more* confusing - with moving something to a local method changing how it works, which is *not* intentional